# Creating a wall where people can post comments

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm not exactly sure what this is called and so I'm not sure how to search for it on google correctly. I tried searching: "How to create a facebook wall swift", "A page where everyone can comment on swift", and "how to make a wall with users being able to post stuff swift". The most results were about Taylor Swift and making a fake Facebook profile. Though some may find this helpful, I, on the other hand, did not :(

So this is what I am trying to accomplish. I want to create a "wall" (I'm sure there is a better terminology for this) where users can post comments. So it's not like a facebook wall where you can post only on another user's "wall". I want a universal wall where any user can post a comment. Could anybody point me to the right direction?

Maybe some part of the Parse documentation or, perhaps, another Stack Overflow post?

Comment: I know this is not the style of question that people like on this forum but please. I would really really like some guidance in this. I have no idea where to look!

Comment: Or, let alone start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not swift but C# but at least it can point you to the right direction:

http://www.joshgreenwald.com/journal/make-a-message-board-with-mvc5-and-signalr2

It is using C#, ASP.net MVC, and SignalR. You might want to look up especially this thing called SignalR because people use it to make the wall thing like you said, for instantaneous, real time communications like wallposts and comments.

Comment: Remember to read the first comment under the page because you need to make a slight change to one of the files in there. All the codes are there and it totally works because I used that before.

Comment: Also if it helps you please click the 'tick' button next to my answer so that a green tick shows. Thank you so much Jae. :)

Comment: Hm... it's not letting me. That's weird... I don't see the green button.

Comment: It's hidden under the arrow that is a downvote arrow. When your mouse is pointing below the downvote arrow area it will appear.

Comment: It's sooo werid. it's not appearing. I am sorry :(

Comment: It's ok no problem. Important thing is your program works. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Parse for you backend database. Its super simple and very powerful. You can find some great tutorials for it too. Here's one that's relevant [Swift & Parse Twitter like App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6kTw_cK3zY)